# Physics2D.IgnoreCollision is nor working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i faced the problem that after some manipulations with code(Dont remember after what exactly) Physics2D.IgnoreCollision stopped working properly. I'm new to stack overflow, and dont know what else to attach here, if something else is needed to understand the situation, please tell me and i will add. Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurnOffGroundCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject ground;
    [SerializeField] GameObject ball;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(ball.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>(),
            ground.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(), true);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(ball.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>(),
            ground.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? What happens when you run the code

Comment: @Jawad After OnTriggerEnter2D ball is supposed to ignore ground collider, but it doesnt.

Comment: @Jawad , yeah, it worked before

Comment: while reading this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html, it says you have to instantiate the bullet and ground first before you can check against their collision

Comment: @Jawad this is Unity, those are fields that will be set in the editor and refer to objects already in the scene.

Comment: Why are you changing the IgnoreCollision state OnTriggerEnter and Exit? Is it intended that the ball will be the object detected by the trigger collider, or is something else intended to trigger it?

Comment: @JHall on Enter ball's collider starts ignoring ground's collider, on exit it should behave normally